# How to set button visibility within DataGridTemplateColumn DataTemplate based on Value of current row

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to add a style trigger to set the visibility of my "Quick Chg" button based on the "State" property on my viewmodel. Visible if State == "Released" and Hidden if State != "Released". I have also tried to do this with a converter but I'm having trouble in either case getting a binding to point back to the row's viewmodel as the datacontext.

```
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Commands">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                    DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                            <Button Margin="0,0,3,0" 
                                    Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" 
                                    Content="Open"/>
                            <Button Margin="0,0,3,0" 
                                    Command="{Binding QuickChangeCommand}" 
                                    Content="Quick Chg"/>
                            <Button Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                    Command="{Binding RevPartCommand}" 
                                    Content="Rev Part"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="File Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Rev}" Header="Rev"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding State}" Header="State"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding CheckedOut}" Header="Ckd Out"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CheckedOutBy}" Header="Ckd Out By"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button Margin="0,0,3,0" 
        Command="{Binding QuickChangeCommand}" 
        Content="Quick Chg">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.State, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Value="Released">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

You could change `AncestorType` to `DataGridRow` if the `State` property is a property of the data object in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thank you. That was my first try but I get a message in Visual Studio saying "Cannot resolve property "State" in data context of object. This property is in the DataGridRow. 

I see now that the warning doesn't matter and that it does work when I run it. Is there a way (or a reason to) tell it the datatype of that object?